# What is "Python interpreter None"?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-launcher

I just created my first application for Google App Engines, which is called "Hello World". It was the first lesson from Google App Engines How-to-get-started tutorial. I tested it on my computer (I am using Windows XP), and it was working just fine - whenever I would open a new window with my web browser (FireFox), I would always be able to see this phrase `Hello, world!!!`, which was a proof that it worked.

Before I created it I didn't know how to save a notepad file as a `.py` file. I asked this [question here and quickly received an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866147/how-to-create-a-py-file-for-google-app-engine)

However, later I received a comment to my question saying this:

> "App Engine does not support Python
>   2.6. You will have better luck using a Python 2.5 release. Sad, but true."

So I uninstalled  Python 2.6.4 and installed Python 2.5.4. Also I uninstalled the Google App Engine Launcher and re-installed it again. While I was installing it a window popped saying that all the necessary prerequisites on my computer were found.

However, when I added my existed application and wanted to run it with App Engine Launcher, a message popped saying this:

> "Python interpreter None not found.
>   Cannot run project
>   E:\python\helloworld. Please confirm
>   these values in your Preferences, or
>   take an appropriate measure to fix it
>   (e.g. install Python)."

I tried deleting my application and re-make it anew - to no avail. What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is basically saying that it cannot find your just installed python interpreter.

It looks like you are on Windows so check your environment variables, particularly PATH and PYTHONPATH, they are probably still pointing to the previous 2.6 installation folder.

Comment: Can you, please, teach me how I could check them? When I click on "Preferences" (in "Edit" on the "Google App Engine Launcher" main window) I get a window with the first line titled as "Python Path" (the caption underneath the line says that it is "A path to a Python executable"). There is a button "Select" right next to it, prompting me to find the path. Is it what you are talking about? if yes, how can I find out where my Python executable is installed?

Comment: I found it! It is in C:\Python25\pythonw.exe on my computer. Yes, it looks like that line was exactly what you were talking about. Thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: I wonder if there's a difference between `python.exe` and `pythonw.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the python interpreter in `Window->Preferences->Google->AppEngine` on your eclipse platform ( of course, I am assuming you are using the GAE Eclipse plugin, if not, disregard my suggestion).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Well, I don't even know what GAE Eclipse plugging is. If it's something that I had to download and install in addition to Google App Engine Launcher, then most likely I am not using it.

Comment: If you like Eclipse, you might want to consider using the Google AppEngine plugin then.

Comment: Did you mean to say "if you don't like Eclipse..." just now?